# How to find initial estimate of roots from graphs?

Tags: numerical-methods, graphing-functions, roots, nonlinear-system

I have `f1(x,y) = x^2 + 3y^2 - 1 = 0` and `f2(x,y) = (x-2)^2 + (y-1)^2 - 4 = 0` I am suppossed to find the roots of these nonlinear equations using Multiple Newton-Rapson Method and I am supposed to guess the initial estimate of the roots by sketching the graphs. How do I guess them?

Comment: @Amzoti simultaneously. It would be better for me if you explain what is the differenece.

Comment: The solutions individually are an ellipse and a circle, respectively.  The solutions simultaneously are any point(s) where they intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ are an [ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) and a [circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle), respectively.

With a small amount of algebra you can determine center, radius, and major and minor axes by inspection.  Then grab some graph paper and estimate where they intersect.

Comment: By the way, What do you mean with "major and minor axes"?